# Display values with the same name in associate array with php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, unique, associative-array

$examscore = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43", "Peter"=>"33");

where "Peter"=>"35" and "Peter"=>"33" are different people but they have the same names

when I print_r($examscore) only one peter is shown but I want to get all names in the array both the same name and non the same name because some of my students have the same names

Comment: you might consider using a unique identifier for your students...

Answer (score -1):

You can not have the same key multiple times in an assoc array. First "Peter" will be overwritten.

Better you create your datastructure as array with arrays.

```
$examscore = [
    ["name" => "Peter", "age" => "35"],
    ["name" => "Ben"  , "age" => "37"],
    ["name" => "Joe"  , "age" => "43"],
    ["name" => "Peter", "age" => "33"]
];
```

When you need sorting, you can use
[array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

---

This will sort `$examscore` order by name ASC, age ASC

```
array_multisort(array_column($examscore, 'name'), SORT_ASC, $examscore);

$examscore = [
    ['name' => 'Ben', 'age' => '37'],
    ['name' => 'Joe', 'age' => '43'],
    ['name' => 'Peter', 'age' => '33'],
    ['name' => 'Peter', 'age' => '35']
]
```

---

This will sort `$examscore` order by age ASC, name ASC

```
array_multisort(array_column($examscore, 'age'), SORT_ASC, $examscore);

$examscore = [
    ['name' => 'Peter', 'age' => '33'],
    ['name' => 'Peter', 'age' => '35'],
    ['name' => 'Ben', 'age' => '37'],
    ['name' => 'Joe', 'age' => '43'],
];
```